# How to make newly created static files accessible in play production mode?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I did some experiments, when running server using `start` command in production mode, if there are new static files generated under the public path, those new static files can not be accessed by clients (404 error). But using `run`, those static files can be accessed.

So my  question is: Is some configuration to enable me to use the production mode while I can access to the newly created static files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use a [frontend HTTP server](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/HTTPServer) that would be best choice.

In such case your files won't be deleted for an example after `play clean-all` as you can store them outside of the app, also with some attention you can optimize serving these files, add caching headers, use `cookie free domain` etc. Finally you can add/edit/remove files without redeploying your application.

Everytime, when I'm using frontend server (which means always) I'm moving all public assets from Play's folder to the HTTP controlled domain and believe me it's just comfortable.

Comment: +1 Yeah friend, I'm just aware for front-end HTTP server. I would recommend to use front end server to serve the static file. It is good choice!

Comment: @biesior & iwawiwi: Thanks so much for the answers! I thought this question would get nowhere and stopped at looking at the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to place any text file (say `dynamic.file.txt`) on (this is done using Play 2.1.1)

> `path-to-project/target/scala-2.10/classes/public/dynamic.file.txt`

while the application started using `play start` command. This is what was happened, I can access newly added file at URL `http://yourdomain/assets/dynamic.file.txt`.

I think, the framework compile all the content on `public` directory. And then, when you are on development mode your files is automatically compiled to the `target` directory. So, when the application is on production mode (using `play start` command), the newly created file (or the *dynamic file* one) can be forced to be placed on `target/scala-xxx/classes/public/*` folder.

You may try it, friend! ;)

---

**Update:**

To be note here, there is the **disadvantage** for using this *hacky* technique. If `play clean` or `play clean-all` commands are executed, **all files** on `target/*` files and folder **would be deleted**. So, be aware!